# locationInView returns invalid co-ordinates in iOS webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, integration

Am trying to integrate the signature in pdf file, which is displaying in UIWebview. I could integrate the signature in pdf file by fixed position say(50,50). Now trying to integrate it in user's single tapping position. First trying to fetch single tapping position of user by code,

```
CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView: self.view];
NSLog(@"tapped location is %@ \n",NSStringFromCGPoint(tapLocation));
NSInteger x,y;
x=tapLocation.x;
y=tapLocation.y;

CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(x,y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

I could fetch the co-ordinates but the signature is not placed in the position where i tapped the pdf file, then found out that, the position of co-ordinate returning as not correct.  For eg., if I tap at position say (50,50) its returning (68,386), then signature is integrated at position (68,386).

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: try with CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView: self.yourWebview];

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda, ya tried [gesture locationInView: webview]; but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure that you are using the correct view in
`[gesture locationInView: self.view];`

Thats all, if you are not sure what view you should choose, try changing to the other subviews in your code.

I can give you a guess, but I would need to see your code first.

If you need any help, just ask (Y)

Comment: ya, i tired with the another subview webview where the exact tapping is occuring. changed to [gesture locationInView:webview]; But still I can't get signature at exact tapping, and the same co-ordinate is fetched as that of previous code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement this using a UIWebView because you need some information that is not available to you. 
The tap location is given in view coordinates. In order to convert this point to PDF page coordinates you need to know the following:

1. where in the web view the page is displayed (you do not know this)
2. the zoom factor used for displaying the page (you do not know this)
3. the cropBox/mediaBox of the PDF page (you do not know this unless you reload the
           page again in a CGPDFDocument)

All the above information is required in order to convert correctly the view coordinates to page coordinates.
The code below shows how to convert a view point to a PDF point.

```
- (CGPoint)convertViewPointToPDFPoint:(CGPoint)viewPoint 
{
    CGPoint pdfPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox);

    int rotation = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(pdfPage);

    switch (rotation) {
        case 90:
        case -270:
            pdfPoint.x = cropBox.size.width * (viewPoint.y - pageRenderRect.origin.y) / pageRenderRect.size.height;
            pdfPoint.y = cropBox.size.height * (viewPoint.x - pageRenderRect.origin.x) / pageRenderRect.size.width;
            break;
        case 180:
        case -180:
            pdfPoint.x = cropBox.size.width * (pageRenderRect.size.width - (viewPoint.x - pageRenderRect.origin.x)) / pageRenderRect.size.width;
            pdfPoint.y = cropBox.size.height * (viewPoint.y - pageRenderRect.origin.y) / pageRenderRect.size.height;
            break;
        case -90:
        case 270:
            pdfPoint.x = cropBox.size.width * (pageRenderRect.size.height - (viewPoint.y - pageRenderRect.origin.y)) / pageRenderRect.size.height;
            pdfPoint.y = cropBox.size.height * (pageRenderRect.size.width - (viewPoint.x - pageRenderRect.origin.x)) / pageRenderRect.size.width;
            break;
        case 0:
        default:
            pdfPoint.x = cropBox.size.width * (viewPoint.x - pageRenderRect.origin.x) / pageRenderRect.size.width;
            pdfPoint.y = cropBox.size.height * (pageRenderRect.size.height - (viewPoint.y - pageRenderRect.origin.y)) / pageRenderRect.size.height;
            break;
    }

    pdfPoint.x = pdfPoint.x + cropBox.origin.x;
    pdfPoint.y = pdfPoint.y+ cropBox.origin.y;

    return pdfPoint;
}
```

- viewPoint is your tap point
- cropBox is the page crop box (#3)
- pageRenderRect is #1 & #2 combined (the position and size of the zoomed PDF page in view coordinates)
- pdfPoint is the point on the page where you draw the signature

The code above is taken from an [article on my blog](http://ipdfdev.com/2011/06/21/links-navigation-in-a-pdf-document-on-iphone-and-ipad/)

Comment: after seeing the code posted, I have a doubt, the position of (0,0) in UIView is top-left, but that of position of (0,0) in UIWebview is bottom-left. By changing the position of UIWebview to (0,0) at top-left can resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this issue. Also tried following code, [webView convertPoint:tapLocation toView:self.window]; converted the tapped location from webview to view,and fetched this value instead of (x,y) but still the signature is not placed at tapped location.

Comment: As I said, you cannot implement this correctly using a UIWebView. You need a custom PDF viewer.